# my custom PHP stdev function VS mysql's STDDEV_POP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, statistics

So I have this code:

```
$arr = array(
  1,2,3,4,5,6
);
$num = count($arr);
$sum = array_sum($arr);
$average = $sum/$num;
foreach($arr as $val) {
  $sum += pow(($val - $average), 2);
}
$stdev = sqrt($sum / ($num - 1));
```

versus

```
SELECT STDDEV_POP(something) FROM table;
```

whereby table is

```
Something
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
'5'
'6'
```

And yet $stdev returns

```
2.7748873851023
```

whereas the select returns `1.707825127659933`

What's wrong with my stdev code?

Comment: You seem to be adding more things to the $sum than just the array numbers in that for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gave me your 1.70

```
$arr = array(
  1,2,3,4,5,6
);
$num = count($arr);
$sum2 = 0;
$sum = array_sum($arr);
$average = $sum/$num;
foreach($arr as $val) {
  $sum2 += pow(($val - $average), 2);
}
$stdev = sqrt($sum2 / ($num));
echo $stdev;exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

**You answer is correct :**

The Basic Formula is :

[image]

**Using [Online Calculator](https://statistics.laerd.com/calculators/standard-deviation-sample-population-calculator.php)**

[image]

**Therefore:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i use this function, it great to my work

```
function find_stdev($arr){
    $a=0;
    foreach($arr as $val) {
      $a += (pow($val,2));
    }
    $n = count($arr);
    $sum = array_sum($arr);
    $a = $a*$n;
    $b = pow($sum,2);
    $c = ($a-$b)/($n*($n-1));

    $stdev = sqrt($c);

    return $stdev;
}
```